# Redirect to custom page when using the [Authorize] tag

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have created a custom user login/register page which interacts with SignInManager and UserManager. It works well when I have a link directly to the login or register page. However when using the [Authorize] tag, the user is redirected to the default built-in login page. How may I change this behaviour? I guess it is an option in the startup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path for the default login page is `/Account/Login`. This is controlled by one of the `ApplicationCookie` options, which can be changed in `ConfigureServices` as follows:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
});
```

See: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/identity/customising-identity#customising-the-login-page